# .HTACCESS - redirect www.example.com/side.php?id=* to www.example.com

Tags: php, string, .htaccess, redirect, root

I have recently assisted in moving a website from a pure development domain to a live site where there used to be a site handled by another CMS system than what we are currently using. Current system is Joomla, but I don't think it matters much for my question.

So with the current site the URLs are rewritten from the standard Joomla format to be stripped of index.php and .html suffix is added in the address, meaning that URLs look like this:

http://example.com/folder/page.html

In the old site handled by another CMS systems the URLs had the following structure:

http://example.com/side.php?id=1

We are a social organisation with many sites linking to us - also quite a few that we are not even aware of - so the problem I need to handle is this: I need to redirect all these dead links on other sites so that they simply get pointed to the root of our site.

Can anyone please explain to me how to make .htaccess redirect as follows:

/side.php?id=* to root of example.com

In this case I mean the * to mean any number as there are naturally alot of pages with different IDs.

It is not of any significance to me if they point at a www. prefix or not.

Thanks in advance for your help, I hope I have not asked a question that's been answered before but my experience with .htaccess is very limited and having searched and tried different solutions didn't do it for me.

Comment: If you are concerned about search engines then you should be concerned with the www subdomain.

Answer (score 2):

In .htaccess in the root folder, add the following:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=\d+
RewriteRule ^side\.php$ http://%{SERVER_NAME}/ [R=301,L,QSD] #Remove the ",QSD" for Apache <2.4.0, or to keep the query string.
```

The R=301 will tell browsers/search engines that the page has permanently been moved.

Comment: Thank you as well, Scott, however this solution is also shooting 404 at me... I don't quite get it.

Comment: Which address are you being redirected to? (You can use example.com for privacy)

Comment: It doesn't redirect at all as far as I can tell - it still just states example.com/side.php?id=1

Comment: Just FYI this rule is not going to work - the RewriteRule will not match the query string portion of the request at all.

Comment: Yes, I just realised and am fixing that now.

Comment: In the query string, do you want ?id=3 to be in the new page? I can cause the entire query string to be removed (is there anything other than ?id=3 ?), but you need Apache 2.4.0 or later. I have added that to the code, you can remove it if you like.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I will get to work on getting things implemented over the next few days - and yes, I would like the query string to be removed. I will try to find out which Apache version is running on the server.

Answer (score 0):

A rule like this should work:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .*
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=\d+
RewriteRule ^side.php http://example.com [L,R=301]
```

This will redirect externally, with a HTTP 301 response (Moved Permanently)

Comment: example.com/side.php?id=1

This is producing a 404 error. I pasted directly from here to my .htaccess and uploaded it via FTP. Do you have any other suggestion?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hmm this should work. Can you add some random characters to your .htaccess to see if it's even being processed? (If it is, it will throw a 500 error)

Comment: It did indeed produce at 500 error adding "hsjdhksjdhskj" and uploading the file so I'm not quite sure what is wrong here.

Comment: /side.php?id=1 is what I'm adding in the browser to the root domain

Comment: I have this in my htaccess as well - I wonder if that's the source of the trouble: "RewriteRule .* index.php [F]" ... I was just thinking that it matches your RewriteCond? Again, I'm a bit in over my head here :)

Comment: Whoa - yes that will match everything! Is this rule above the rule I gave you? In that case, it will match every URI that gets to it and rewrite it to index.php, and then send the 403 Forbidden code.

Comment: Hmmm, I am in a bit of a rush just now but I will send you or post my full .htaccess (changed slightly for anonymity) so that you can give me a suggestion based on that. I can only say that the side is working with the above posted RewriteRule - question is if it is compatible with your suggestion

Comment: I'm heading out now and will have patchy internet access for a few days, so perhaps one of the others can help you out :)

Answer (score 0):

What you need here is some [301 Moved Permanently](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301) responses to let browsers and search engines know that you're moving pages to a new location. Instead of using a mod_rewrite to redirect *all* requests to this side.php page, I would analyze each page of your old website and determine where all the content has been moved. Armed with this, use the htaccess [Rewrite directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) to inform browsers of individual pages being moved

```
Redirect 301 /side.php?id=123 /about_us.html
Redirect 301 /side.php?id=456 /contact_us.html
```

I recommend this method because it redirects those who navigate to the outdated page to the new page that has similar content to the old one they were requesting instead of just redirecting them all to your home page.

Comment: Well, the problem is that ALOT of sites link to old site and there is not a one-to-one structure (at all) so doing it like this is not really an option

Comment: @CasperDamsgaard Well that's a shame. In that case, you could just `Redirect 301 /side.php /`

Comment: This is doing the actual redirect correctly - however it is leaving in the snip of code after side.php ... meaning that the link it types in the browser looks like this: example.com/?id=1

Comment: Is there any way to get rid of that? :)

Comment: @CasperDamsgaard Apache docs have nothing on query strings and Redirect. My guess would be to try `Redirect 301 /side.php?id= /` but I have a hunch that that won't work so you'd best stick with `mod_rewrite` as others have suggested.